# How to replace files in Google Colab

Tags: python, file, google-colaboratory

This is my code to download and unzip files from google drive.

```
fileId = drive.CreateFile({'id': '1tQq-ihnTbRj6GlObBrm17Ob6j1XHHJL2'}) 
print (fileId['title'])
fileId.GetContentFile('tweets_research.zip')
!unzip tweets_research.zip -d ./
```

But there are already some files and I want to replace them. It is giving me
this option.

[image]
But it doesn't matter whatever I press on my keyboard it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-o` option to overwrite files, e.g.,

```
!unzip -o tweets_research.zip -d ./
```

Comment: `caution: filename not matched:  ./` this is the error I am getting after adding `-o`

Answer (score 1):

You can echo your choice as input to your command by using a pipe.

in case of rename:

```
!echo "r"| unzip tweets_research.zip -d ./
```